# how to combine two columns into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have two tables, tb1(account, status) and tbl2(account status_ex). For example

```
account    status
0001       A
0002       CD
0003       AB

account    status_ex
0001       78
0002       NULL
0003       9
```

I want to write a query to combine the two status columns, the result table should be like

```
account    status
0001       A78
0002       CD
0003       AB9
```

I tried following query

```
select tb1.account, 
  stuff(tbl1.status, len(tbl.status)+1, len(tbl.status), tb2.status_ex) as status
from tb1 left join tb2
on tbl.account=tb2.accont
```

But the result is not correct, what did I do is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  tb1.account, 
  status = COALESCE(tb1.status, '') + COALESCE(tb2.status, '')
FROM tb1 INNER JOIN tb2 -- is LEFT JOIN right? Not sure.
ON tb1.account = tb2.account;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IsNull()` and just concatenate the values (see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91865/4)):

```
select t1.account,
  isnull(t1.status, '') + isnull(t2.status_ex, '') status
from tb1 t1
inner join tb2 t2
  on t1.account = t2.account
```

You did not post what the datatype is of `status_ex` so if the `status_ex` field is a different datatype, then you will need to `cast()` it:

```
select t1.account,
  isnull(t1.status, '') 
    + isnull(cast(t2.status_ex as varchar(10)), '') status
from tb1 t1
inner join tb2 t2
  on t1.account = t2.account
```